# Possible to use NuGet.Config Custom Config

Tags: xml, nuget, config

Does anyone know, is it possible to define custom config items for expansion during some custom package sources? i.e.

```
<config>
  <add key="myKey" value="myValue" />
</config>
<packageSources>
  <add key="$myKey$ Released Packages" value="..." />
</packageSources>
```